# C++ returning boolean as 95

Tags: c++, return, boolean

Problem with returning booleans in c++..

```
bool find( const TrieNode &node, const string word )
{

    if (word.length() == 0)
    {
         if (node.isWord)
         {
         cout << "TRUE" << endl;
         return true;
         }

         else
         {
         cout << "FALSE" << endl;
         return false;
         }
    }

    char firstletter = word.at(0);
    int index = firstletter - 'a';

    if (node.letters[index] == NULL)
    {
    return false;
    }

    else
    {
    find (*node.letters[index],word.substr(1,(word.length() - 1)));
    }

}
```

in my main I have

```
cout << find(*mynode,"word") << endl;
```

would yield to :

FALSE

95

clearly, a cout of FALSE means that the function returns false.. However, when I print out the result of the function, I get 95 which evaluates to true.. Any reason why it could be doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your missing a final return statement, so your getting whatever is in the low byte of `EAX`, which is random garbage. your probably want `return true;` at the very end of your function.

Your should pump the warning level of your compiler as it should be telling you this (something along the lines of "not all control paths return a value").

Comment: Curious though that the stream insertion operator actually prints 95, which probably means there is no "bool" insertion and it just casts to an int?

Comment: @edA-qa: its more than likely widened/promoted to an `int`, but under most (x86) systems, `bool` is a byte, which makes it a numeric and not confined to 1/0.

Comment: It's scary that a thing which is an obvious mistake (undefined behaviour in C, illegal in C++) compiles without a warning unless you explicitly ask for it. Another good reason to never compile with anything than maximum warning level.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with your final `if` statement:

```
if (node.letters[index] == NULL) {
    return false;
}
else {
    //if execution gets here, the return value of the function is undefined
    find (*node.letters[index],word.substr(1,(word.length() - 1)));
}
```

...perhaps try:

```
if (node.letters[index] == NULL) {
    return false;
}
else {
    return find (*node.letters[index],word.substr(1,(word.length() - 1)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem. I was under the impression that return is implicit? One of my friends working on the same assignment didn't need to put a return statement (although his code was somewhat different)

Comment: One habit that helps avoid such mistakes (as well as being more concise and readable - at least once you get used to it - is to prefer `return ...`, e.g. `return node.letters[index] && find(...);`.  Whenever there's an `if (...) return ...; else return ...;` it's a good idea, but especially when there's a `return` with a hardcoded `true` and/or `false`.  It encourages you to get your logic sorted out to make a positive assertion out of the statement - much like variables should be called `is_x` and not `is_not_x` - doing that consistently helps code comprehension and correctness.

Comment: @IrWin: `return` is only implicit from `int main(...)`, which returns `EXIT_SUCCESS` (typically 0) if leaving the scope with no explicit `return` statement having executed.  (That's specific to C++ - you must return in C.)